# Why am I getting null entry for parameter on action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller which has an action like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Assign(int reportId, List<int> clientIds)
    {

          // stuff
          return View();
    }
```

When I call it from the view from a table like this:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Assign", "Report", FormMethod.Post, new { reportId = 1} ))
    {
      ...
          <input type="checkbox" name="clientIds" value="@item.Id" checked>
```

I'm getting an error saying

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'reportId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Assign(Int32, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32])'

As far as I can see the controller should be getting the value 1 for reportId - can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

I realise I could (should) be using a view model to get data from the client to the action but I need to do it this way for now...

Comment: If you make reportId a hidden field instead,it will definitely post back to the server - that could be the issue here, is that POST operations don't route query string parameters as action method parameters...

Comment: Thanks @BrianMains - if you do an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using the wrong overload of `BeginForm()`and adding `reportId` as a html attribute, not a route value. You need to use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod%29) where the 3rd parameter is `object routeValues`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Assign", "Report", new { reportId = 1 }, FormMethod.Post))
```